# Is there a name for this class of functions?

Tags: functions, soft-question

I'm involved in a research project in which the following type of function is common. I am wondering if such functions have a name, or if they are common elsewhere, in order to get a better handle on their use and their general properties.

Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $C,D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ for some $n, m \geq 1$. Suppose, also, that $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq D$. I am interested in the functions $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ that satisfy the two conditions:

(i) if $x \in B$, then $f(x) \in D$,

(ii) if $y \in C$, then $\mathrm{preim}_f(\{y\}) \subseteq A$.

Comment: I don't know of any standard name for such functions. Note that the two conditions can be written more concisely as (i) $f(B)\subseteq D$ and (ii) $f^{-1}(C) \subseteq A$. (not that conciseness is the ultimate goal, but it's good to get used to this standard notation) Note also that the definition would make sense regardless of whether $A\subseteq B$ or $C\subseteq D$.

Comment: You might find a name for such functions in topology when $A,B,C,D$ meet certain conditions, such as $B$ and $C$ being compact and $A, D$ being open. But even then it will be a niche subject, not something widely recognized.